# MySQL join two tables to find all rows EXCEPT the row with the max value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I'm trying to write a query that will find all rows in a group EXCEPT the row with the max value.  I have a query so far that finds the row with the max value, but now I need to find all the rest of the rows.  Here is a SQLFiddle with the two databases and sample data.  I also have the query that finds the max rows.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/514d2/33

For those that don't want to use SQLFiddle...
Tablename: listings
Tablename: bids

```
SELECT listings.end_date, listings.user_id, listings.title, 
  listings.auc_fp, listings.id, listings.auc_image1
FROM listings 
JOIN bids b1 
ON b1.listing_id=listings.id 
LEFT JOIN bids b2 
ON b2.listing_id=listings.id AND b1.bid < b2.bid
WHERE b1.user_id = 1
AND b2.bid IS NULL
AND listings.end_date > NOW()
ORDER BY listings.list_ts DESC
```

Above is the query that find the max rows.  I'm trying to join the listings table with the bids table on listings.id=bids.listing_id.  Then I need to find all the rows where a user ($user or user "1") has bid on that listing.  Then I need to exclude the listings where the user is has the max bid (which is what the query above does).

I originally thought I could use the query above as a subquery to exclude the listings where the user is the max bidder.  But I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it and I'm not that good with subqueries.

Comment: Which is the value column?

Comment: bids.bid is the value column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that answer was revised several times based on the comments below.

```
SELECT
    lst.end_date,
    lst.title,
    lst.auc_fp,
    lst.id as listing_id,
    lst.auc_image1,
    b.user_id as bid_user_id,
    b.bid as bid_amount,
    maxbids.maxbid as maxbid_for_listing
FROM listings lst
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) maxbid
    FROM bids b
    GROUP BY listing_id
) maxbids ON lst.id = maxbids.listing_id
INNER JOIN bids maxusers ON maxusers.bid = maxbids.maxbid AND maxusers.listing_id = maxbids.listing_id
INNER JOIN bids b ON
    maxbids.listing_id = b.listing_Id AND
    b.bid < maxbids.maxbid AND
    b.user_id <> maxusers.user_id
WHERE lst.end_date > NOW()
ORDER BY lst.list_ts DESC
```

Comment: Oh, and here's the fiddle using the schema from your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/514d2/51

Comment: That's finding the listings where the user has the high bid.  Actually, I'm not seeing where user "1" is specified so maybe it's finding all the current listings where there is a high bid.  What I'm trying to do is exclude the listings where the user "1" is has the high bid, but return the listings where user "1" has placed a bid.

Comment: If a user has 2 bids on a listing, one of which is the max bid, do you still want the lesser bid returned.  Or, for that listing, do you want nothing returned, because the user also has the max bid?

Comment: Actually since the listings where the user is the max bid is already be shown elsewhere, I'd like to exclude any listings where the user is the current high bidder.

Comment: Ok, I've revised.  See new answer above, and new fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8818e/8.  Note I had to insert one extra row at line 87 of the schema in order to have anything to return.  The way the schema sample is written, only 6469 and 6472 have bids.  User 1 is the max user on both of those, so nothing would be returned.  By adding a bid for user 2 on 6469, which is not the max bid, I can demonstrate that a non-maximum bidding user is being selected for a listing.

Comment: I have it running now and have tested it by manually changing bidders in the database and it seems to be working correctly.  Thank you so much for your help.  This was a question I could find no answers for.  You're a genius!